# gtk symbol lookup error

Tags: gtk

I have a code for loading data:

```
GFileInputStream* ins;
GFile* gf = g_file_new_for_path(file_path);
ins = g_file_read(gf, NULL, NULL);

mw->pix = gdk_pixbuf_new_from_stream(G_INPUT_STREAM(ins), NULL, NULL);
gtk_image_view_set_pixbuf (GTK_IMAGE_VIEW (mw->view), mw->pix, TRUE);
g_input_stream_close(G_INPUT_STREAM(ins), NULL, NULL);
```

When i try to run app i see error:  symbol lookup error:  undefined symbol: gdk_pixbuf_new_from_stream

What's wrong?

Thank you

Comment: I think that you should also mention how you compiled this code and on what platform.

Comment: My platform is GNU/Linux Debian 5.04. gtk version - 2.16.0
glib virsion - 2.19.7

Answer (score 2):

When you use some symbol you should link against the library containing that symbol, `-lgdk_pixbuf-2.0` (or better `$(pkg-config --libs gdk-pixbuf-2.0)` in the case of `gdk_pixbuf_new_from_stream`.

Comment: Thank you for reply.

I have -lgdk_pixbuf-2.0 in my makefile, but it's not help.

Comment: I have in my makefile: GTK_LIBS = -L/usr/local/lib -lgtk-x11-2.0 -lgdk-x11-2.0 -lgtkimageview -latk-1.0 -lgio-2.0 -lpangoft2-1.0 -lgdk_pixbuf-2.0 -lpangocairo-1.0 -lcairo -lpango-1.0 -lfreetype -lz -lfontconfig -lgobject-2.0 -lgmodule-2.0 -lglib-2.0